# exact sql query executed by Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

the question seems clear enough, but I'll add a case

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
  if(context.mytable.Any(row => row.myfield == 2))
  {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

I am new to Entity Framework.
I don't know how to check the exact sql query executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a similar question here: [How to view generated SQL from Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039082/how-to-view-generated-sql-from-entity-framework)

To sum up, your choices are:

- [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)
- SQL Server Profiler
- [Entity Framework Profiler](http://www.efprof.com/)

See the referenced question for details.

Answer (score 8):

As the above answers state, you can use SQL Profiler, LINQPad, EF Profiler, etc.

Another little known (some might say lazy) trick is to use `ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()` extension method.

Just cast your query as `ObjectQuery<T>`.

```
var query = context.mytable.Any(row => row.myfield == 2));
var trace = ((ObjectQuery<MyTable>)query).ToTraceString();
```

It will spit out the SQL that is to be executed.

Very handy for last-minute logging.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to SQL Server, you can use the SQL Profiler in order to obtain the SQL that is generated.