# LINQ and Generated sql

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

suppose my LINQ query is like

```
var qry = from c in nwEntitiesContext.CategorySet.AsEnumerable()  
           let products = this.GetProducts().WithCategoryID(c.CategoryID)  
           select new Model.Category  
           {  
               ID = c.CategoryID,  
               Name = c.CategoryName,  
               Products = new Model.LazyList<Core.Model.Product>(products)  

           };  
 return qry.AsQueryable();
```

i just want to know what query it will generate at runtime....how to see what query it is generating from VS2010 IDE when we run the code in debug mode....guide me step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: without using linq pad can't we see the generated sql. because sometime data retrieval is slow then user definitely like to see what sql is generating. please advice.

Comment: @user728750 - you are not showing the code for `GetProducts()` but if you are making an EF query to get all products with a certain categoryId, this could be resulting in a DB call for **EVERY** `Category` in the DB. After you called `AsEnumerable` you are in object space (EF made a query and fetched all the categories). After that depending on what you do, you could be indeed making a DB query for every category which would explain the performance problems you are facing. You can check what's going on at SQL level by running e.g. SQL Profiler (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

There is not much to see here - it will just select all fields from the `Category` table since you call `AsEnumerable` thus fetching all the data from the `Category` table into memory. After that you are in object space. Well, depending on what `this.GetProducts()` does - and my guess it makes another EF query fetching the results into memory. If that's the case, I would strongly recommend you to post another question with this code and the code of your `GetProducts` method so that we can take a look and rewrite this in a more optimal way.  (Apart from this, you are projecting onto a mapped entity `Model.Category` which again won't (and should not) work with Linq-to-Entities.)

Before reading into your query I was going to recommend doing something like this:

```
string sqlQueryString = ((ObjectQuery)qry).ToTraceString();
```

But that won't work since you are mixing Linq-to-Entities with Linq-to-objects and you will actually have several queries executed in case `GetProducts` queries EF. You can separate the part with your EF query and see the SQL like this though:

```
string sqlString = nwEntitiesContext.CategorySet.ToTraceString();
```

but as I mentioned earlier - that would just select everything from the `Categories` table.

In your case (unless you rewrite your code in a drastic way), you actually want to see what queries are run against the DB when you execute the code and enumerate the results of the queries. See this question:
[exact sql query executed by Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385756/exact-sql-query-executed-by-entity-framework/4385856#4385856)

Your choices are `SQL Server Profiler` and [Entity Framework Profiler](http://www.efprof.com/). You can also try out `LinqPad`, but in general I still recommend you to describe what your queries are doing in more detail (and most probably rewrite them in a more optimal way before proceeding).

Answer (score 0):

This will produce `SELECT * FROM Categories`. Nothing more. Once you call `AsEnumerable` you are in Linq-to-objects and there is no way to get back to Linq-to-entities (`AsQueryable` doesn't do that).

If you want to see what query is generated use SQL Profiler or any method described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx).