# Linq to Entities - Filter sub table

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have two tables in my Edmx, Categories and Items. The items table has a "Visible" bool field.

I want to return the categories table with the attached Items table with only the records where Visible = True.

Can you give me an example of how to only return the items where Visible = True?

I have tried the following which hasn't worked

var categoryList = from cl in db.Categories
                                   where cl.Items.Any(item => item .Visible == true)
                                   select cl

Thanks

Mark

SQL Query is:

ADO.NET:Execute Reader "SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Category_Name] AS [Category_Name], 
[Extent1].[CategoryNote] AS [CategoryNote], 
[Extent1].[CategoryOrder] AS [CategoryOrder]
FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[CategoryID]) AND ([Extent2].[Visible] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Visible] = 1)
)"
The command text "SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[Category_Name] AS [Category_Name], 
[Extent1].[CategoryNote] AS [CategoryNote], 
[Extent1].[CategoryOrder] AS [CategoryOrder]
FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[CategoryID]) AND ([Extent2].[Visible] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Visible] = 1)
)" was executed on connection

Answer (score 1):

you code should work!!

try the following code:

```
db.Categories.Where(c => c.Items.Any(i => (bool)i.Visible)).Select(c => c)
```

you run the SQL Profiler / IntelliTrace to check the generated code.

EDIT: I modified the code
EDIT2: Check this code ( I reversed the query)

```
db.Items.Where(i => i.Visible != null && (bool)i.Visible).SelectMany(i => i.Categories);
```

Comment: Using you code gives the following errors:

Delegate 'System.Func<Models.Categories,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<Models.Items,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: this means that `Visible` field is null able!! try the modified code\

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm afraid it still returns both Visible and Invisible items

Comment: CAn u try: `db.Categories.Where(c => c.Items.Any(i => i.Visible != null && (bool)i.Visible)).Select(c => c)` I'm sure if it's going to work on EF or not, but it will work isA

Comment: Have just tried that and it still returns all the items I'm afraid

Comment: Would you please put the generated sql query?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. I usually just use IntelliTrace

Comment: Check this article will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039082/how-to-view-generated-sql-from-entity-framework/4040501#4040501 you can get it also from IntelliTrace

Comment: I've modified the original question to include the generated sql query