# LINQ and selection rows from big database

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have some database ang now it contains a table with about 100 rows. But in future it will have not 100 but 1 000 000+ rows and I have to be careful with my web application I'm developing now.

Problem is next: at web page I need to create paged list what will show records to user. And here is a sample of code that I plan to use

```
public IQueryable<MyTable> GetRows(int from, int to)
{
   var queryRes = (from row in SomeDataContext.MyTable
                   order by row.id
                   select row).AsQueriable();
   return queryRes.Take(to).Skip(from);
}
```

It is only sample of code. I did not run it. 
But question is what will go on in this case? I see tow scenarios

1. It will load all rows from database and at server side and records in range from 'from' to 'to' will be returned. Other will be ignored. In this case my application will have big troubles. Imagine load 1 000 000 rows from database every time. It will be disaster.
2. It will construct SQL request what will return only rows I need without loading others. That's exactly what I need.

I think that it will be 2 scenario but I'm not sure and can't check it. Am I correct?

Comment: @GertArnold Does it matter? Its a Linq queryable. As an interface, it could be L2S L2EF or L2nH and it would still work just as well.

Comment: I reckon a good plan would be to set `SomeDataContext.Log` to something (e.g. `Console.Out`) and then you can see exactly what SQL is being used.

Comment: I ask because `SomeDataContext` could be anything. It suggests L2S, but who knows? And the abstractions are leaky. each engine has its own strategy to implement paging. L2E requires you to sort before Skip, for instance.

Comment: I use Entity Framework and it is something like MyEntities SomeDataContext = new MyEntities();

Answer (score 4):

As a side-note, you don't have to call `AsQueryable`. It is enough to do

```
var queryRes = SomeDataContext.MyTable.OrderBy(r => r.Id);
return queryRes.Take(to).Skip(from);
```

And to answer your question - scenario 2 will be executed. You can always check the generated SQL by using the SQL Server Profiler, but in case you are using Entity Framework, you can even do `queryRes.ToString()`. And as @Aron correctly pointed out - the query will be actually executed against the database only when enumerating the results (e.g. calling `queryRes.ToList()`).

These questions address the issue of looking up the SQL code in more detail:

- [How to view generated SQL from Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039082/how-to-view-generated-sql-from-entity-framework)
- [exact sql query executed by Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385756/exact-sql-query-executed-by-entity-framework/4385856)

Comment: `queryRes.ToString()` will not give the generated SQL. You need to use `.ToTraceString()` and you need to cast the query as a `ObejctQuery<T>
` before you can do that

Comment: @JensKloster - have you tried it? My EF is a bit rusty and I might remember incorrectly, but `ToTraceString` was the old way of doing it, while in the newer EF versions `ToString` returns the SQL generated query. Will need to double-check though.

Comment: I didn't knew that :) I tested in Ef 4.1 and there it didn't work. But in the newer versions of EF, you could very well be right. It **would** make sence to let the `ToString()` return the generated SQL

Comment: @JensKloster - according to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/0dcf90e5-ec80-436a-bf18-5731aba0f045/ `ToString` should do the trick. I will be able to test it later today.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, neither 1 nor 2 is correct. Running the code DOES NOT hit the database. It constructs an expression tree. The calling code can still modify the expression tree further without hitting the database.

With the IQueryable interface no SQL is run. It is at the point when you call `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` that the underlying Linq Provider converts the WHOLE expression into a query. In this case a SQL query, and then run it.

So for example, with this code. You could have

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = from x in GetRows(10, 10)
            where x.Id > 1000
            select x;
    foreach(var f in foo)
    {
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

The sql that is actually run will actually be closer to

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM 
(SELECT a,b,c, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) as row_number
FROM Table
WHERE id > 1000) t0
WHERE to.row_number BETWEEN 10 and 20;
```

To be honest you are going about this wrong. You don't need a GetRows method. I would directly call the Linq query when constructing the table itself. You should take a look at the `IRepository` pattern that MVC scaffolding uses.

Finally if this is meant to be called as a WebQuery for AJAX I would look at the two OData implementations in .net (WCF Data Services and WebAPI OData).

Answer (score 1):

You are right. 
The 2. scenario is what will happen. When the query is eventuallty exectuted.

I Would sugges to reverse the Take - Skip, so you start by Skip

```
queryRes.Skip(from).Take(to)
```

Debuggen this method will not make any calls to the database. It just returns the query - not the resualt.

If you want to test exactly what will happen, try download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - it is a great to for demystifying linq queries.